# Is this version of Subset Product Problem NPComplete?

Tags: complexity-theory

Subset Product Problem is $NP-Complete$. Given a promise that the product contains exactly 1 occurrences of each of its prime factor is the problem still $NP-Complete$?

Seems to be the case but couldn't find any references. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by reduction from [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).